# What do these asterisks and dots mean in SAS code?

Tags: sas

I am trying to understand the following SAS code snippet:

```
SUM( (list=.)*. , (list=.B)*. , (list=.D)*. , (list=.Q)*.  )
```

where `list` contains several elements. My understanding so far is that `SUM` will create a new list as an output of the same length as `list`, summing the respective elements in the four entries. I guess `list=.` or `list=.B` etc maps the elements of `list` to `1` where the equality is satisfied and to `0` where it is not, but what does it mean for an element to be equal to a dot `.`? And what kind of quantity can `.B` be? Also, what does it mean to multiply by a dot, as in `variable * .`?

EDIT:

Upon further investigation I found out that "." stands for a NaN numeric value in SAS, so I guess `list=.` produces a new list where all NaN elements in `list` are set to `1`, and all regular numbers are set to `0`. But what does it mean to then multiply the resulting new list by `.`? And what could `.B` be?

Comment: `.`  is a missing value. .A to .Z and ._ are special missing values.  NaN is something used in some other languages to indicate a value is unknown.  There is no concept of a "list" in SAS.  Instead datasets have variables.  In that code LIST is the name of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted kind of looks like SAS code, but not sensible SAS code.

**SUM(...)** in that code is a function call.  The function that can take one or more arguments.

**=** in that code is the equality comparison operator.

***** in the code is the multiplication operator.

**.** and **.B** and **.D** and **.Q** are missing values.  The first is the normal missing values and the other three are examples of the other 27 special missing values that SAS supports.

Normal arithmetic, such as `X+Y` or `A*B`,  will produce a missing result if any of the arguments are missing.  But the SUM(,) function ignores the missing values. So the result is only missing if all of the arguments are missing.

The result of a boolean expression, such as `LIST=.D` , is either 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE).  Note that SAS only uses actual **Boolean** logic, it does not use the Tri-level logic that some other languages use.  So `X=.` is true when the value of X is missing and false when it is not missing (including any of the 27 special missing values).

So far the code begins to look like an attempt to test if LIST is any of those missing values.  So something like:

```
SUM( (list=.) , (list=.B) , (list=.D) , (list=.Q)  )
```

This will be 1 when LIST is any of those four values.  And 0 when none of the test is true.

So it is the same test as using the IN operator. Like this

```
list in (. .B .D .Q)
```

But by adding the multiplication by a missing value is what makes it nonsense.  Because that will always result in a missing result.  So you could just replaced the whole SUM() function call with a period to indicate you wanted a missing value no matter what value LIST had.

If you substitute actual numbers for those missing multiplicand values.

```
SUM( (list=.)*1 , (list=.B)*2 , (list=.D)*3 , (list=.Q)*4  )
```

Then perhaps it might make some sense.  Now the result is a value that is coded 1 when LIST is missing and 2 when LIST is special missing .B, 3 when .D, 4 when .Q and zero otherwise.

Comment: The snippet I have shown included only the parts I did not understand from the code I'm looking at. The actual SUM also has entries that evaluate to numbers. Since you pointed out that SUM ignores any missing values, this now makes more sense to me, thank you!

Comment: Probably it is more the fact that adding zero does not change the sum.  Since the boolean expressions will return zero when false multiplying that by any value will return either the value or zero depending on whether the expression is true or false.